# rspec setup method in separate file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to create a setup file for rspec so that my '_spec.rb' test only have 'it' blocks like so:

setup.rb

```
require 'rspec'

module Setup
 describe "setup" do

 before(:each) do
  @foo = 'hello'
  'do something'
 end

 after(:each) do
 'do something'
 end
end
```

spec/test_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../setup.rb'

include Setup

it "test_sample" do
 puts @foo
 'do test'
end
```

This returns undefined variable. Can someone shine light onto my issue? I have multiple tests that I want to share the same setup for, and I don't want to repeat the setup for each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rspec's `configure` method for this:

```
# in spec_helper.rb (or setup.rb)
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
  ...
  end

  config.after(:each) do
  ...
  end
end
```

See [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration) for more info on setting the configuration.